# Aggressive garbage collector strategy

Tags: java, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I am running an application that creates and forgets large amounts of objects, the amount of long existing objects does grow slowly, but this is very little compared to short lived objects. This is a desktop application with high availability requirements, it needs to be turned on 24 hours per day. Most of the work is done on a single thread, this thread will just use all CPU it can get its hands.

In the past we have seen the following under heavy load:
The used heap space slowly goes up as the garbage collector collects less than the amount of memory newly allocated, the used heap size slowly grows and eventually comes near the specified max heap. At that point the garbage collector will kick in heavily and start using a huge amount of resources to prevent going over the max heap size. This slows the application down (easily 10x as slow) and at this point most of times the GC will succeed to clean up the garbage after a few minutes or fail and throw an `OutOfMemoryException`, both of them are not really acceptable.

The hardware used is a quad core processor with at least 4GB of memory running 64 bit Linux, all of that we can use if needed. Currently the application is heavily using a single core, which is using most of its time running a single core/thread. The other cores are mostly idle and could be used for garbage collection.

I have a feeling the garbage collector should be collecting more aggressively at an early stage, well before it runs out of memory. Our application does not have any throughput issues, low pause time requirements are a bit more important than throughput, but far less important than not getting near the max heap size. It is acceptable if the single busy thread runs at only 75% of the current speed, as long as it means the garbage collector can keep up with the creation. So in short, a steady decrease of performance is better than the sudden drop we see now.

I have read [Java SE 6 HotSpot[tm] Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) thoroughly, which means I understand the options well, however I still find it hard to chose the right settings as my requirements are a bit different from what is discussed in the paper.

Currently I am using the ParallelGC with the option `-XX:GCTimeRatio=4`. This works a bit better than the default setting for time ratio, but I have a feeling the GC is allowed to run more by that setting than it does.

For monitoring I am using jconsole and jvisualvm mostly.

I would like to know what garbage collection options you recommend for the above situation. Also which GC debug output can I look at to understand the bottle neck better.

**EDIT:**
I understand a very good option here is to create less garbage, this is something we are really considering, however I would like to know how we can tackle this with GC tuning, as that is something we can do much more easily and roll out more quickly than changing large amounts of the source code. Also I have ran the different memory profilers and I understand what the garbage is used by, and there by I know it consists of objects that could be collected.

I am using:

```
java version "1.6.0_27-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_27-ea-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.2-b03, mixed mode)
```

With JVM parameters:

```
-Xmx1024M and -XX:GCTimeRatio=4
```

**Edit in reply to Matts comments:**
Most memory (and cpu) goes towards constructing objects that represent the current situation. Some of these will be discarded right away as the situation changes rapidly, some others will have a medium life time if no updates come in for a while.

Comment: Consider posting all of the VM arguments you're using now.

Comment: I'm using Java 6, the arguments are ony -Xmx1024M and -XX:GCTimeRatio=4  (Jvm detects itself as a server and uses the parallel GC). The application will also run mostly on 200M (actually it seems to run a bit better as it will be triggered to clean up sooner and then it has less of a flooding of work).

Comment: can you define "medium life time" in "number of young collections" terms? it sounds like "if no updates come in for a while" implies that the rate of object allocation slows dramatically during this period in which case the interval between young collections should extend correspondingly. If so the same (small) MTT may be fine.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You don't mention which build of the JVM you're running, this is crucial info. You also don't mention how long the app tends to run for (e.g. is it for the length of a working day? a week? less?)

A few other points

2. If you are continually leaking objects into tenured because you're allocating at a rate faster than your young gen can be swept then your generations are incorrectly sized. You will need to do some proper analysis of the behaviour of your app to be able to size them correctly, you can use visualgc for this.
3. the throughput collector is designed to accept a single, large pause as opposed to many smaller pauses, the benefit is it is a compacting collector and it enables higher total throughput
4. CMS exists to serve the other end of the spectrum, i.e. many more much much smaller pauses but lower total throughput. The downside is it is not compacting so fragmentation can be a problem. The fragmentation issue was improved in 6u26 so if you're not on that build then it may be upgrade time. Note that the "bleeding into tenured" effect you have remarked on exacerbates the fragmentation issue and, given time, this will lead to promotion failures (aka unscheduled full gc and associates STW pause). I have previously written an answer about this on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322761/java-cms-gc-behaviours/5332704#5332704)

   5. If you're running a 64bit JVM with >4GB RAM and a recent enough JVM, make sure you `-XX:+UseCompressedOops` otherwise you're simply wasting space as a 64bit JVM occupies ~1.5x the space of a 32bit JVM for the same workload without it (and if you're not, upgrade to get access to more RAM)

You may also want to read [another answer I've written on this subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762300/tuning-gc-for-java-audio-application/4767048#4767048) which goes into sizing your survivor spaces & eden appropriately. Basically what you want to achieve is;

- eden big enough that it is not collected too often
- survivor spaces sized to match the tenuring threshold
- a tenuring threshold set to ensure, as much as possible, that only truly long lived objects make it into tenured

Therefore say you had a 6G heap, you might do something like 5G eden + 16M survivor spaces + a tenuring threshold of 1.

The basic process is

1. allocate into eden
2. eden fills up
3. live objects swept into the to survivor space
4. live objects in from survivor space either copied to the to space or promoted to tenured (depending on tenuring threshold & space available & no of times they've been copied from 1 to the other)
5. anything left in eden is swept away

Therefore, given spaces appropriately sized for your application's allocation profile, it's perfectly possible to configure the system such that it handles the load nicely. A few caveats to this;

1. you need some long running tests to do this properly (e.g. can take days to hit the CMS fragmentation problem)
2. you need to do each test a few times to get good results
3. you need to change 1 thing at a time in the GC config
4. you need to be able to present a reasonably repeatable workload to the app otherwise it will be difficult to objectively compare results from different test runs
5. this will get really hard to do reliably if the workload is unpredictable and has massive peaks/troughs

Points 1-3 mean this can take ages to get right. On the other hand you may be able to make it good enough v quickly, it depends how anal you are!

Finally, echoing Peter Lawrey's point, you can save a lot of bother (albeit introducing some other bother) if you are really rigorous about object allocation.

Comment: "If your main work thread is aggressively consuming CPU then you will ultimately be starving the GC threads" the OP says he has a multi-core computer, so a GC thread should always be able to run.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I am using a fairly new JVM (1.6 u27). It seems indeed that I am leaking objects into the tenured generation.

Comment: @Raedwald forgot about the single threadedness so edited that bit out

Comment: @Thirler based on your config and comment about 200M working set, you may find it is sufficient to simply use `-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Xmn1536m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 -XX:SurvivorRatio=90 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -verbose:gc` which means 2G heap, 1.5G eden, 8M survivor spaces (eden:survivor size is 1:90 so each survivor is 1/(90+2) of young gen), occupy 90% of the survivor space, promote after an object has survived 1 collection

Comment: I will try this, I am also going to install visualgc, as jconsole is a bit harder to use it seems. Why is it that having -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1 is something you do when you don't want objects to be tenured quickly?

Comment: the idea is you size the generations & spaces such that it is highly likely that anything that has survived a young collection really is a long lived object and hence should be promoted to tenured. Therefore don't waste time ping ponging it across the survivor spaces n times, just get it into tenured. If you get the sizes wrong then this is the slow bleed that leads to too frequent full GCs. Alternatively if you have many objects that have a moderate lifetime then you can increase the MTT as required.

Comment: (continuing) So basically if you still see the bleed into tenured then you can remove the MTT setting and use `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution` to determine the typical ages and what an appropriate value for MTT is. http://kirk.blog-city.com/why_do_i_have_this_long_gc_pause.htm has is a good practical example of this subject.

Comment: I see, with your settings i still see bleeding into the tenured generation, however it seems a lot closer to what I need than the current situation. I will update my question to reflect why (the graphical situation is updated very often and there is always one last version that could live for a while). I will also have to look more closely at the debug output. What I did notice is that the tenuring threshold the GC determines bounces around  a bit (sometimes one, sometimes max).

Comment: well bleeding in and of itself can be fine, the Q is how quickly it will fill tenured causing a full GC & how often this will happen relative to the typical life of the app. Re MTT, you want to fix it to (say) 8 and then watch the tenuring distribution stats. This may help you choose a better number. It may also be your survivor spaces are too small. Finally you may want to start a new Q on survivor space tuning once you've collected detailed stats on this aspect of your allocation profile.

Answer (score 6):

The [`G1GC`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/G1.html) algorithm, which has been introduced with stable `Java 1.7` is doing well. You have to just specify maximum pause time you want to live with in your application. JVM will take care of all other things for you.

Key parameters:

```
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000
```

There are some more parameters to be configured. If you are using 4 GB RAM, configure region size as 4 GB/2048 blocks, which is roughly 2 MB

```
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=2
```

If you have 8 core CPU, fine tune two more parameters

```
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=4 -XX:ConcGCThreads=2
```

Apart from these parameters, leave other parameters values to default like

`-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio` etc.

Have a look at [oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/G1.html) for more details about `G1GC`.

```
-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=n
```

Sets the size of a G1 region. The value will be a power of two and can range from 1MB to 32MB. The goal is to have around 2048 regions based on the minimum Java heap size.

```
 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200
```

Sets a target value for desired maximum pause time. The default value is 200 milliseconds. The specified value does not adapt to your heap size.

```
-XX:ParallelGCThreads=n
```

Sets the value of the STW worker threads. Sets the value of n to the number of logical processors. The value of n is the same as the number of logical processors up to a value of 8.

If there are more than eight logical processors, sets the value of n to approximately 5/8 of the logical processors. This works in most cases except for larger SPARC systems where the value of n can be approximately 5/16 of the logical processors.

```
-XX:ConcGCThreads=n
```

**Recommendations** from oracle:

When you evaluate and fine-tune G1 GC, keep the following recommendations in mind:

1. **Young Generation Size**: Avoid explicitly setting young generation size with the `-Xmn` option or any or other related option such as `-XX:NewRatio`.  `Fixing the size of the young generation overrides the target pause-time goal`.
2. **Pause Time Goals:** When you evaluate or tune any garbage collection, there is always a latency versus throughput trade-off. The G1 GC is an incremental garbage collector with uniform pauses, but also more overhead on the application threads. `The throughput goal for the G1 GC is 90 percent application time and 10 percent garbage collection time`.

Recently I have replaced CMS with G1GC algorithm for 4 GB heap with almost equal division of young gen & old gen. I set the `MaxGCPause` Time and results are awesome.

Answer (score 3):

You can try reducing the new size.  This will case it to make more, smaller collections.  However it can cause these short lived objects to be passed into tenured space.  On the other hand you can try increasing the NewSize which means less objects will pass out of the young generation.

My preference however is to create less garbage and the GC will behave in a more consistent manner.  Instead of creating objects freely, try re-using them or recycling objects. You have to be careful this this doesn't cause more trouble than its worth, but you can reduce the amount of garbage created significantly in some applications. I suggest using a memory profiler e.g. YourKit to help you identify the biggest hitters.

An extreme case is to create so little garbage it doesn't collect all day (even minor collections). It possible for a server side application (but may not be possible for a GUI application)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I understand creating less objects would be a good thing, but short term that is not an option. Jconsole shows 'PS old gen' increasing. Which ideally I think should not be needed as most of these elements can be cleaned up and are quiet new, I will see if increasing the eden space helps.

Comment: Increasing the Eden space can reduce the change that a short lived object will need to be copied and cleaned up later.

Answer (score 2):

The first VM options I'd try are increasing the `NewSize` and `MaxNewSize` and using one of the parallel GC algorithms (try UseConcMarkSweepGC which is designed to "keep garbage collection pauses short").

To confirm that the pauses you're seeing are due to GC, turn on verbose GC logging (`-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps`). More info about how to read these logs is available [online](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#cms.measurements).

To understand the bottleneck, run the app in a profiler. Take a heap snapshot. Then, let the app do its thing for a while. Take another heap snapshot. In order to see what's taking up all the space, look for whatever there are a lot more of after the second heap snapshot. Visual VM can do this, but also consider [MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Alternatively, consider using `-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` so that you get a snapshot of the real problem, and you don't have to reproduce it in another environment. The heap that's saved can be analyzed with the same tools -- MAT etc..

However, you may be getting an `OutOfMemoryException` either because you have a memory leak or because you're running with too small a max heap size. The verbose GC logging should help you answer both of these questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question to state that I understand how the memory is used. I know for sure is free and can be collected, it just isn't. Using jvisuamvm (and -verbose:gc) I can see that the GC uses several small burst per minute and then eventually it will near 80% of max heap and start using up to 20% cpu constantly.

Comment: Just to confirm, you've already captured both the GC logs and a heap dump when there was an OOME? Consider posting parts of the GC logs along with your current analysis of what's happening.